# How can you query posts by advance custom field when the value is a serialized array?

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, meta-query, array

**Bottom for resolution**
Im going crazy I think. I cannot figure this out for the life of me. I have an advanced custom field that is a select box. The select box has multiple values and allows for multi-selections. I made 1 post and multi-selected 3 values in this drop down.

I now need to be able to show all posts that have 1 of those values. So I made a new page, and started googling trying find code to do this, and I tried many many thing, but none seem to actually work. Now, if I change this ACF to a single select, I can do it just fine. But since it is this multi select serialized array, I can't figure out the syntax.

Currently, my page with the below code is returning many post titles, including the one I want, but also including a bunch that I don't want.

keywords: Make a page to query posts with advanced custom field that is an array, query acf fields array

```
acf meta_key = author_link
meta_value in db = a:3:{i:0;s:12:"Triz-Journal";i:1;s:18:"Matt Campbelll III";i:2;s:8:"Garfield";}
```

I should be able to return that titles of only my 1 post containing 1 of those 3 values. I will never be searching more than 1 value.

Here is the code I am using at the moment, but I have also tried many others

```
// args
$args = array(
'numberposts'   => -1,
'post_type'     => 'post',
'meta_query'    => array(
    array(
        'key'       => 'author_link',
        'value'     => $authorname,
    )
)
);


// query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
var_dump($the_query->request);
?>

<?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>

<?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <p>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">

            <?php the_title(); ?>
        </a>
    </p>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post(). ?>
```

VAR_DUMP QUERY RESULTS

```
string(408) "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta   ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) 
WHERE 1=1 AND 
( ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'author_link' AND 
CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) = 'Garfield' ) ) AND 
wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR 
wp_posts.post_status = 'private') 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC 
LIMIT 0, 20"
```

Currently, the query is returning many post titles, but not the only post that actually have the acf value of "Garfield" in it.

Can anyone help further?

**RESOLUTION----------**
For whatever reason, the query was pulling back multiple posts including the ones I needed. Thanks to the guys that responded, I got it figured out. Inside the query loop, I used get field to test the array of each individual post in the loop. Then, I only echo'd the title if it had a meta value matching the one I needed (which was fetched from the URL).

**page-authors.php**

```
//Get authorname from URL
<?php
if (isset($_GET['authorname'])) {
 $authorname = $_GET['authorname'];
} else {
 $authorname = 'none';
}
?>

// meta query my acf field name called author_link 
// which is a multi value array not a single text value. 
// query it for the value from the url
$args = array(
'numberposts'   => -1,
'post_type'     => 'post',
'meta_query'    => array(
    array(
        'key'       => 'author_link',
        'value'     => '"' . $authorname . '"',
        'compare'   => 'LIKE',
    )
)
);


// query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

// loop through the query results and test 
// them further for the meta value matching  what came from the url.
// then echo the title   if it matches
<?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>
<?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <p>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <?php if( in_array( $authorname, get_field('author_link') ) )
                {
                 echo the_title();
                } ?>    
        </a>
    </p>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post(). ?>
```

Comment: I'd remove the `meta_key` line from your args as it's not needed but that shouldn't cause your current problems - perhaps do a `var_dump($the_query->request);` after the `new` and run and tweak the SQL command directly against your database to see what's happening...

Comment: Thank you for the info. I just posted the results from the var_dump after I removed the meta_key. It is still pulling a list of a lot of posts instead of the only 1 post that has the meta value Garfield. Is there a way I can query the results further and implode that array and test them further before printing the list out?

Comment: You have to do a LIKE meta query if the full value isn't identical to what you're querying for, which it won't be if the data is in a serialized string. Note though that a LIKE query can be pretty slow. Storing data as serialized strings is far from ideal if you need to query against it.

Comment: When I do use a Like query it pulls back everything, including the 1 post I want. What about, if I leave it as is, but then implode the array and test for the value 'Garfield' before I echo its title? Is there a way to pull back the meta_values of a specific post by post id?

Comment: If the query without LIKE returns many posts except the post you want, & the query with LIKE returns many posts including the post you want, then I'd guess you actually have many posts with a (non-serialized) "Garfield" value, perhaps left over from your previous experimenting ... so either just remove the bogus author_links from these, or put double quotes around the value arg (`'"' . $authorname . '"'`), & your original query with the LIKE should work as you expect...

Answer (score 1):

I would advise using the built-in ACF functions for this.  Elliot has provided a full toolbox for you and documentation for all field types:

```
<?php

// Conditional statement (Single Value)   
if(get_field('page_layout') == "col_1")
{
    //...
}


//Conditional statement (Multiple Values)
if( in_array( 'col_1', get_field('page_layout') ) )
{
    //...
}
?>
```

Check out the ACF documentation:
http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/select/

Comment: This is fine for pulling values and working with them which I know how to do, but how does this translate into a full query that returns all posts with a certain value in its array?? I am using their documentation but the query section is a little bit out of date, and currently it is what I am trying to use. I just added a query var dump.

Comment: Could I somehow get the Post ID and query it inside a loop to build the list?

`if( in_array( 'Garfield', get_field('author_link') ) )`
`{`
`for each Get its post ID`
`query it by post id`
`echo title result`
`}`

Comment: What is the slug of your custom field?  Assuming you created a Field Group in ACF and then individual fields inside of that, is "author_link" the Field Name of the custom field you want to filter posts with?